# Calculating total length of a union of time intervals presented at a table

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

I wish to calculate the total time length of the union of time intervals presented at a table.

For example, given the following:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Temp;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | start               | end                 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2010-01-01 10:00:00 | 2010-01-01 11:00:00 |
|    2 | 2010-01-01 12:00:00 | 2010-01-01 14:00:00 |
|    3 | 2010-01-01 13:00:00 | 2010-01-01 15:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to somehow select the total time length, which is in this case 4 hours (the total time length of the union of the intervals (10:00, 11:00) and (12:00, 15:00).

I do not care if the output will be in seconds (either `INT` or `FLOAT`), or in any other sensible format.

It may worth mentioning that I am not sure about the order of the date in the table. It is not guaranteed that either the start datetimes or the end datetimes are sorted in any manner. I also can't say anything about a "typical" datetime interval - it may be more than one day, for example.

I **can** say, however, that any single time interval is of non-negative length. That is, for any record, the end date is at least as late as the start date.

---

I know how to accomplish that task in simple programming languages (such as Python); I just wonder if there's a sensible way to do so in pure MySQL. If not, I'll just select everything and process it in some other programming language. Hence, *"it is impossible to accomplish this in MySQL without some very serious effort"* may also serve as a legitimate answer to this question...

---

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682151/calculate-total-seconds-of-time-intervals) which is similar, but is about `tsql`. The solution presented there is using syntax which is unknown to MySQL such as `cross apply`, and my attempts to translate it have failed.

---

As requested, here are queries to create an example data:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp (id INT, start DATETIME, end DATETIME);
INSERT INTO Temp (id, start, end) VALUES (1, '2010-01-01 10:00', '2010-01-01 11:00');
INSERT INTO Temp (id, start, end) VALUES (2, '2010-01-01 13:00', '2010-01-01 14:00');
INSERT INTO Temp (id, start, end) VALUES (3, '2010-01-01 11:00', '2010-01-01 16:00');
```

So the data will be as follows:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | start               | end                 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2010-01-01 10:00:00 | 2010-01-01 11:00:00 |
|    2 | 2010-01-01 13:00:00 | 2010-01-01 14:00:00 |
|    3 | 2010-01-01 11:00:00 | 2010-01-01 16:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The result on this example data should be 6 hours.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your terminology; what is a `DDL`? In my example the desired result is 4 hours - and I wrote that in my post. What else is missing?

Comment: @Bach DDL stands for 'Data Definition Language`. Strawberry is not keen on taking your data example and writing `CREATE TABLE....` and `INSERT INTO....` statements. He'd prefer you provided that in your question.

Comment: @TomMac thanks for the explanation, I've added a new example with its DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

This is probably best done outside of SQL

**For Those That Like Painful Queries**

You could create a query that attempts to decide whether there is a row elsewhere in the table that overlaps the `end` column. If there is not then try to find out how much time is in between the `end` column and the nearest `start` column aka `gap`.

Then take the maximum `end` from the whole table, subtract the minimum `start` from the whole table and finally subtract the total of the `gap` columns:

```
select
unix_timestamp(maxEnd)-unix_timestamp(minSt)-sum(case when hasEndOverlap=0 then gap else 0 end) as unionSecs,
(unix_timestamp(maxEnd)-unix_timestamp(minSt)-sum(case when hasEndOverlap=0 then gap else 0 end))/(60*60) as unionHrs
from
(
 select c.id,c.`start`,c.`end`,
 c.minSt,c.maxEnd,
 c.hasEndOverlap,
 @prevSt,
 unix_timestamp(@prevSt)-unix_timestamp(c.`end`) as gap,
 @prevSt := c.`start`
 from
 (
  select t.id,t.`start`,t.`end`,
  a.minSt,a.maxEnd,
  case when min(te.id) is null and t.`end` != a.maxEnd then 0 else 1 end as hasEndOverlap
  from Temp t
  left outer join Temp te on t.`end` >= te.`start` and t.`end` <= te.`end` and t.id != te.id
  join (select min(`start`) as minSt,max(`end`) as maxEnd from test.`Temp`) a
  group by t.id,t.`start`,t.`end`
  ) c
  join (select @prevSt := '1970-01-01') r
  order by c.`end` desc
) d
group by minSt,maxEnd
;
```

Comment: I don't think that will do, as the overlaps do not have to be with a subsequent record.

Comment: The query includes an `order by` to try and cope with that. Can you include an example of where the overlaps are not with a subsequent record in your sample data, please?

Comment: I have tried your code on my new example data and the result was 4 union hours (and not 6, as needed).

Comment: Ah. I see. Misunderstood the data somewhat. Have tried again.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I'll have a deeper look now.